# Return count of matches with find/replace using sed

Tags: sed, find, replace, wc

I'm trying to get a count of the number of replaced strings with `find` and `sed`.

What I'm starting with:

```
# find . -name \*.php -exec sed -i -e "s|finddddd|replaceeeee|g" {} \;
```

This replaces four matches of "finddddd".  After running this command, I reset my test file so the command will work again.

I tried using `wc -l`,  The command found and replaced for instances of "findddd", but shows 0 matches found on the line below.

```
# find . -name \*.php -exec sed -i -e "s|finddddd|replaceeeee|g" {} \; | wc -l
0
```

Also tried moving `wc -l` in the command, but get errors.

```
find . -name \*.php -exec sed -i -e "s|finddddd|replaceeeee|g" {}| wc -l;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
0
```

and

```
find . -name \*.php -exec sed -i -e "s|finddddd|replaceeeee|g" | wc -l {} \;
wc: {}: No such file or directory
wc: ;: No such file or directory
0 total
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

How do I get the base command to output count of matches?

Comment: When using the `-i` option, `sed` doesn't produce any output, it writes the results back to the file. So there's nothing to pipe to `wc`.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get `sed` to tell you how many replacements it made. You could write a perl script that does it.

Comment: Do you want the number of replacements or the number of lines where a replacement was made? I mean, should two replacements on a single line be counted once or twice?

Comment: FWIW, the reason your third command block (the one ending with `{}| wc -l;`) is failing is because you're doing `find` ... `-exec` without an ***escaped*** semicolon; i.e., you have `;` where you need `\;` (or, if you prefer, `';'` or `";"`).

Comment: @terdon, that would count as 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool. `wc` will count lines of input but since you're using `sed -i`, there are no lines printed so nothing for `wc` to count. Even without it, the `sed` command would have printed all lines of the file so it still would not have worked correctly. Here's a different approach:

1. Use perl instead

   ```
   find . -name \*.php \
     -exec perl -i -lpe 's|finddddd|replaceeeee|g && print STDERR "."' {} \;  \
   2>&1 | wc -l
   ```

   The trick is to print a `.` each time a replacement succeeded, then pass the results through `wc`. The `-i` flag edits the file in place and the `-l` causes a newline to be added to each `print` call. The `-p` tells perl to print each input line after applying the script passed by `-e`. Because we're editing the file in place, we need to print to STDERR to avoid having the `.` added to the file. The STDERR is then redirected to STDOUT (`2>&1`) which lets us use `wc`.
2. If you need to count multiple replacements on the same line separately, use perl again:

   ```
   find . -name \*.php -exec \
       perl -i -lpe '$l++ while s|finddddd|replaceeeee|; 
       END{print STDERR $l}' {} + 2>&1
   ```

   Here, perl itself is doing the counting. Note that I used `+` instead of `\;` to end the `-exec` call. This means that it will attempt to combine the commands into as few as possible. If you don't have too many `.php` files,  they will all be passed to a single `perl` run and the number will be correct. If you have too many files, this will fail and you should use this instead:

   ```
   find . -name \*.php -exec \
     perl -lpe '$l++ while s|finddddd|replaceeeee|; 
                END{print STDERR $l}' {} + 2>&1 >/dev/null | 
     awk '{k+=$1; }END{print k}'
   ```

Comment: I was able to invert the quotes to `'s|finddddd|replaceeeee|g && print STDERR "."'` -- it works, but are there any hidden pitfalls?

Comment: @acoder not that I can think of. It's just doing the replacement and printing, pretty straightforward really.